# iOS how to find the larger dimension of a CGRect?

Tags: ios, geometry, core-graphics, cgrect

I know that core graphics has a number of helper functions, such as `CGRectGetMidX`. I'm working with autolayout and use code like

```
    float height = self.view.bounds.size.height * 0.08;
    UIImageView* key = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,height,height)];
```

I can use ternary operator, but it looks really ugly and unreadable:

```
float dimension = (self.view.bounds.size.height> self.view.bounds.size.width ?  self.view.bounds.size.height: self.view.bounds.size.width) * 0.08;
UIImageView* key = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,dimension,dimension)]
```

Is there a way to replace the `self.view.bounds.size.height` with **a function to get the maximum dimension of a rectangle, like getMaxDimension(self.view.bounds)?**

I know I can write my own with if statements, but I'm interested if there's something in the iOS that lets me do this with a single built in function, this way I can use the same approach across multiple projects.

Answer (score 4):

I think

```
MAX(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds));
```

is probably the most readable code you'll get from builtin functions.
Geometry functions:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/
MAX is a macro from the objective-c runtime.
If you want the code to be more readable than that, just write your own function.